# Displaying my Bloc in mutiple "zone"?

Tags: magento, layout, adminhtml

I am working on a Slider extension for Magento, I want to be able to display my slider in one of this positions : top_left, top_right, top_center, bottom_left/right/center ! and be able to choose this position from my Admin backend whith a DropList or somthing like.
Can you help please :) !
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution i found is to add an Observer with this event :

> controller_action_layout_load_before

Then we load the layout in it :

```
public function addBlock(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
   $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
   $layout->addHandle(ThePositionYouWant);
   return $this;
}
```

In your Layout put he different position you want :

```
<position_name>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="BlockName" name="Name" before="-" template="YourBlockTemplate"/>
     </reference>
</position_name>

    <position_name2>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="BlockName" name="Name" after="-" template="YourBlockTemplate"/>
         </reference>
    </position_name2>
```

And it Works. 
Hope this will help :) !

Comment: Clever solution.  Of course once you have `$layout` you can get & add any block without using XML.